# convert HTML code from page source to regular page source - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a web page, that include another web page source. It looks like

```
<html>
....
<div id="content">
{"note":"\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<!--[if IE 9]>\n\t\t\t<script src=\"\/js\/PIE\/PIE_IE9.js\"><\/script>\n\t\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\"...
</div>
```

so I have a string like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<!--[if IE 9]>\n\t\t\t<script src=\"\/js\/PIE\/PIE_IE9.js\"><\/script>\n\t\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\"...
```

and I would like to get

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><!--[if IE 9]><script src="\js\PIE\PIE_IE9.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet".
```

Is there any PHP function that can remove this special chars like" `\n, \t, \`"...
I just need a regular HTML code.

Sorry for my english

Comment: why dont you do it in the source? wow that is bad to have all `\n` in final output mate... no proper use..

Comment: Is it a json string? If so, see `json_decode` -> http://th1.php.net/json_decode.

Comment: If you render that within another page, it will be malformed HTML.

Comment: json_decode works fine. thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, there are better ways to do this, however:

```
$string = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<!--[if IE 9]>\n\t\t\t<script src=\"\/js\/PIE\/PIE_IE9.js\"><\/script>\n\t\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\"";
echo preg_replace('/\r|\n|\t|\\\/', '', $string);
```

this will replace the special chars `\n`, `\t`, `\r` and `\`